# Generate SQL query with inserted params

Tags: c#, sql

I want to generate an SQL-query string like this one:

```
INSERT INTO students (id, name) VALUES (?, ?);
```

How can I avoid possible sql-injections, if some real values are inserted instead of signs `?`?

```
string GetQuery() => "INSERT INTO students (id, name) VALUES (7, @name)"
                         .Replace("@name", "bad value from user");
```

Is there any function to prepare parameters in C#? Escaping slashes or quotes? Make a note, I **don't have** any connection with SQL server and **don't want** to use EntityFramework.

Comment: use parametrized SQL Query for detail check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: See [Using Parameters for SQL Server queries](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2981/using-parameters-for-sql-server-queries-and-stored-procedures/) and a **great many more** great articles out there! Just do some research....

Comment: @rashfmnb solutions in your articles don't produce an output query in string format. They just send an sql query to a database (that's impossible for me, I don't have any sql connetcion). What I needed is a function to escape string.

Answer (score 1):

use parametrized SQL Query for detail check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx)

and here is the sample code from same link For Entity Framework

```
using (AdventureWorksEntities context = new AdventureWorksEntities())
{
    // Create a query that takes two parameters.
    string queryString =
        @"SELECT VALUE Contact FROM AdventureWorksEntities.Contacts 
                AS Contact WHERE Contact.LastName = @ln AND
                Contact.FirstName = @fn";

    ObjectQuery<Contact> contactQuery =
        new ObjectQuery<Contact>(queryString, context);

    // Add parameters to the collection.
    contactQuery.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("ln", "Adams"));
    contactQuery.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("fn", "Frances"));

    // Iterate through the collection of Contact items.
    foreach (Contact result in contactQuery)
        Console.WriteLine("Last Name: {0}; First Name: {1}",
        result.LastName, result.FirstName);
}
```

For ADO.NET use this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090(v=vs.100).aspx)

and here is the sample code from the same link

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string connectionString =
            "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Northwind;"
            + "Integrated Security=true";

        // Provide the query string with a parameter placeholder.
        string queryString =
            "SELECT ProductID, UnitPrice, ProductName from dbo.products "
                + "WHERE UnitPrice > @pricePoint "
                + "ORDER BY UnitPrice DESC;";

        // Specify the parameter value.
        int paramValue = 5;

        // Create and open the connection in a using block. This
        // ensures that all resources will be closed and disposed
        // when the code exits.
        using (SqlConnection connection =
            new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            // Create the Command and Parameter objects.
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pricePoint", paramValue);

            // Open the connection in a try/catch block. 
            // Create and execute the DataReader, writing the result
            // set to the console window.
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}\t{2}",
                        reader[0], reader[1], reader[2]);
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```